# Getting a duplicate value in my table. Not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Alright, so for some reason in the following code I end up getting a duplicate of the very first object in the table. Assignments should only end up with three objects (there are only 3 GA's seeded in the database), but for some reason the first assignment gets duplicated. What is the cause?:

```
    @courses = Course.all
    @gas = Ga.all
    @assignments = Assignment.all


    @gas.each do |ga|
        this_assignment = Assignment.create(assigned_GA: ga.name, credit_hours: '0')
        @courses.each do |course|
            if ga.hours >= 20
                break
            end
            if course.gas.empty?
                    this_assignment.courses << course
                    this_assignment.save!
                    this_assignment.credit_hours = this_assignment.credit_hours + course.credit_hours
                    this_assignment.save!
                    course.gas << ga
                    course.save!
                    ga.hours = ga.hours + course.credit_hours
                    ga.save!

            end
            if ga.hours >= 20
                break
            end
        end
        this_assignment.save!
        @assignments << this_assignment
    end
```

Comment: First of all I have a question why are you doing `.save!` after each `<<` operator like `this_assignment.courses << course` and then `this_assignment.save!` because the course is automatically created and associated. And I guess this can be the one duplicating your assignment: `@assignments << this_assignment` (Not Sure)

Comment: Well spent a while doing some testing. Just like to always do a .save! Anyways, the @assignments << this_assignment is still only hit 3 times, so I don't see why that would be causing it (did a test, used a 'count' variable beneath it to make sure and it only hits 3 times).

Comment: can you try by removing `@assignments << this_assignment`.

Comment: If I do that then there's nothing that will actually fill the table though. If you notice it's the only thing actually adding to the @assignments

Comment: But you are creating the assignment here right? `Assignment.create(assigned_GA: ga.name, credit_hours: '0')`

Comment: The assignment itself is created there, yes, but it is added to the list of @assignments (the one being passed to the view) via the '@assignments << this_assignment' line

Answer (score 1):

This is todo with  `.all` being lazy: `@assignments` is not an array, it is a relation object.

The first time you call a method that requires the relation to be loaded (this includes a bunch of methods from array, such as `collect`), rails executes the query and stores the result in an array that is hidden inside the relation.

In particular this happens when you do `@assignments << this_assignment` for the first time: Rails executes the query, stores it in an array and *then* calls `<<` on that array

Since `this_assignment` has been persisted it will already be in the array and so you get a duplicate.

On subsequent iterations through the loop, the relation is already loaded so the database is not requeried.

You could fix this by changing the line where you load the assignments to

```
@assignments = Assignment.all.load
```

(If you need @assignments to be a relation) or

```
@assignments = Assignment.all.to_a
```

If you'd rather it just be a plain array.